# "Den" or "det" in Swedish

Tags: grammar, articles, meaning, swedish

I am native Swedish speaker and I have a problem that the language seems to have no grammar in some cases. For instance there is both "en lag" and "ett lag" meaning completely different things but the word "lag" is the same sound and same spelling, but the difference is in the meaning of the word. So you can't know from just the word "lag" whether it is "ett lag" or "en lag".

It seems completely arbitrary whether you should say "en lag" or "ett lag" but the meanings are different.

It seems like there is no logic there or at least something I never saw in other languages i.e. the meaning of the word determines the case. It is the same difference in English in "an" or "a" and there it is the sound of the word which determines the case.

In all other cases besides Swedish, you can know from the word itself what the gender or case should be e.g. English has "a" or "an", German has "der", "die", "das" with very distinct clear rules so that you know, given a word, how to write the definite article.

Comment: I don't think the rules for German "der", "die", "das" are very clear at all. They are actually complicated enough that German textbooks or courses that I've seen recommend memorizing every German noun with an article. My understanding is that native speakers disagree about the gender of some German words.

Comment: @sumelic But compared to Swedish, German is very regular.

Comment: I don't know enough about each language to say. I just wanted to point out that Swedish is far from the only European language where the grammatical gender of a noun can be relatively hard to predict just from the form of the noun.

Comment: German (and most languages with gender) has similar situations where the essentially two lemmata with different genders have the same nominative singular surface form.  eg https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Teil#German, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mar#Spanish.

Comment: There area also cases like *Worte* vs *Wörter*, where gender happens to be the same but the difference in the plurals again implies distinct lemmata.

Comment: Your last paragraph is completely wrong. In English, the choice of _a_ or _an_ is purely phonetic, and has no grammatical implications whatever. In languages with grammatical gender, in some (eg Latin, Italian, Spanish, Russian, Swahili) you can usually guess the gender from the form of the word (but not always). In others (eg German, Swedish, Welsh, Hebrew) the correlation with form is much weaker and you generally can't guess the gender from the form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many languages have such an ambiguity built in. It's very common that you can't tell the morphosyntactic properties of a word or even its phonological interactions just from its form, even given certain generalizations.

- In German if you encounter the word *Schlüssel* on its own you don't know whether you have one key (*der*) or multiple (*die*) keys.
- In French if you encounter the word *grammaire* you don't know whether it's the set of rules governing a language (*la*) or a book describing those rules (*le*).
- In English if you encounter the name *Taylor* without context you don't know know whether to make a subsequent pronoun agree as *him* or *her*.
- In Hebrew if you encounter the word *אוכל* /oχel/ you don't know whether it's the participle "eating" or the noun "food".
- In Spanish if you encounter the word *flor* for the first time you can't guess the gender. If you encounter the word *mano* for the first time and apply the usual rules you will guess wrong.
- In German if you apply a generalization about words ending in *el* to *Bibel* you will be wrong.
- In English if you try to decide between "a" and "an" using the same rule for *hour* and *heel* you will get one of them wrong.
- In French if you encounter the word *haricot* for the first time you won't know whether the definite article is "le haricot" or "l'haricot".

Each of these is one example of large sets of ambiguous cases!

In short, the entry in the lexicon presumably carries some of the information needed to settle these cases — not just the meaning.

Comment: "In English if you try to decide between "a" and "an" using the same rule for universal and unusual you will get one of them wrong" - this is the only one I disagree with. You can't tell from the spelling, sure, but the rule is based on the pronunciation ("universal" starts with a consonant sound /j/, while "unusual" has a vowel).

Comment: @Draconis Hmm, true. See if this revision is any better...

Comment: In my (British) English we say "a history" and "a heel". What am I not understanding?

Comment: @Wilson I should probably not have generalized across a country. Can you help me identify a dialect where they say "an history"?

Comment: Not sure I've heard "an history" before. I've heard "an hotel" though, which is rare but prescribed, and I personally associate with Kentish dialects.

Comment: @Wilson Thanks! Updated. Funny enough, here in Canada news anchors will sometimes say "an historical X". Do you have that variation?

Comment: How about "an honor" or "an hour" for something most dialects probably agree on? Or are you looking for words where the /h/ is actually pronounced, but they still take "an"? (But in that case, I would venture to guess that in dialects that use "an" in front of those, the /h/ is not actually pronounced...)

Comment: @LjL Good idea. Though I must share [this photo](https://imgur.com/9CSUSUn) spotted here in Toronto... :)

Comment: I don't agree with the "him/her in English"-example. You could just say they/them/etc. Besides, it's a universal problem unrelated to ones understanding of the English language. It's not a "fixed" rule like in the OP's example with "lag" which could be either a team, a law or the fluid of something pickled.

Answer (score 5):

> I have a problem that the language seems to have no grammar in some cases. For instance there is both "en lag" and "ett lag" meaning completely different things but the word "lag" is the same sound and same spelling, but the difference is in the meaning of the word.

The grammar is there, even if it's confused by something else.

As you probably know, in Swedish every noun is either "ett" or "en". It's unpredictable sometimes, but this feature is inherent in the noun.

**Why is "lag" sometimes "en" and sometimes "ett"?** It's because actually there are two/three separate words here.

- One is `laget`, "the team".
- One is `lagen`, "the law".
- Another is `lagen`, the juice/brine.

Each has its gender; they are never mixed up. Swedish people never say "en lag" to mean "a team".

> It seems like there is no logic there or at least something I never saw in other languages i.e. the meaning of the word determines the case.

It's mostly arbitrary, like I said. But there are certain generalisations. For example,

- living beings are mostly "en". "en häst", "en fluga", "en pojka", "en främling", "en svamp".
- Masses, like water and slime are usually "det": "vattnet", "slemmet", "trädet". This is what explains "laget", "the team". I guess you'd expect "juice/brine" to fall under this category but for whatever reason it doesn't.
- Nouns for humans/humanoids that are both genders are usually "ett": "ett barn", "ett troll", alternative explanation for "ett lag".
- Nouns which are historically derived from verbs are almost always "en". "lag",  "the law", comes from "ligga". That's why it's "en lag".

You see, there is method to the madness. Not always a perfectly reliable method, but it's undeniably there.

Comment: Just realised, the word for "juice/brine" probably *also* comes from *ligga* (in the sense of "steeping something in water"), which would be why it's "en".

Comment: Could you explain whether _skit_ (shit, dirt, damn) is a single word or several, when they say _”hela skiten”_ but _”inte ett skit”_ ?

Comment: @J-mster that's a tricky one; *skit* is derived from the verb *skita* so it's "en", on the other hand it's a mass as in my second bulletpoint, so it's "ett". Whether it's one word or several though is up for debate. I don't think there's a clear answer.

Comment: En other helpful rule is that if the words plural is the same as singular, it is an "ett" word e.g. ett träd/flera träd. Of course that means you need to know the words plural.

Answer (score 3):

Two, three [**homonyms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) `lag` (different meanings, identically written/sounding words), here with two genders for the articles: `en/et`.

A German example with the same phenomenon:

- die Steuer = the tax,
- das Steuer = the steering wheel.

It is a helpful coincidence that the articles differ.

> Languages with several lingual origins/cultures, like English (romance+germanic), or a larger reuse of a word for different contexts (both *Steuer*'s have their origin in *steer*), may have more homonyms, whereas an artificial language like Esperanto tries to avoid homonyms.